# A command in a .bat file is unrecognized when the .bat file is called from an Inno Setup but works fine when I run the bat file manually

Tags: batch-file, inno-setup

I have the following .bat file:

```
fbwfmgr /enable
.
.
.
fbwfmgr /addexclusion c: "some folder 1"
fbwfmgr /addexclusion c: "some folder 2"
.
.
.
```

which I'm calling from the `[Run]` section in my Inno Setup like this:

```
Filename: "{tmp}\set_write_protection_rules.bat";
```

I have also tried this:

```
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/c ""{tmp}\set_write_protection_rules.bat""";
```

I always get the message

> 'fbwfmgr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

If I run the .bat file by double clicking on it it works, if I run it from a cmd window myself it works. What am I missing here?

I'm running this on a Windows Embedded Standard x64 system logged in as the administrator.

---

EDIT:

Adding the full path to the `fbwfmgr.exe` does not solve the issue (I have also manually looked that that's the actual location of `fbwfmgr.exe`):

```
%systemroot%\system32\fbwfmgr.exe /enable
```

I found [a similar thread here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/758207dc-a888-428f-8b50-04c1620677ad/running-batch-file-to-enable-fbwf-from-vb-application?forum=quebeceefs) where the OP is having the same problem while running the .bat file from vbs, no solution seems to have been found there. From a suggestion there to cut the middle man I've tried calling `fbwfmgr` directly from Inno Setup with the following line:

```
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "c/ ""fbwfmgr /enable""";
```

but to no use. It just opens an empty console window. When I try to call `fbwfmgr` from there, it is not recognized.

Comment: What is `fbwfmgr`? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Isn't it, because there's only 64-bit version of the `fbwfmgr` in the `C:\Windows\System32` on the system?*

As Inno Setup in a 32-bit application, it by default [gets redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) (32-bit version of `C:\Windows\System32`). If there's no 32-bit version of `fbwfmgr` in the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`, Inno Setup cannot find it.

Add the [`Flags: 64bit`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=64bit) to make Inno Setup find 64-bit version of the `fbwfmgr`.

Also, there's no point running a `.exe` application via a command interpreter (`cmd.exe`).

```
[Run]
Filename: "fbwfmgr.exe"; Parameters: "/enable"; Flags: 64bit
```

---

With a batch file, the mechanics is bit more complicated. Inno Setup by default (being a 32-bit applications) runs a 32-bit `cmd.exe`, which in turns looks into the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`. If you add the `Flags: 64bit`, Inno Setup will run a 64-bit `cmd.exe`, which will look into the `C:\Windows\System32`.

```
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\set_write_protection_rules.bat"; Flags: 64bit
```

---

Or use the [64-bit install mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls).

---

*For a similar question, see [PowerShell script executed from Inno Setup is failing with "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed - error 80040154"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63169767/850848)*.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to provide the path to `fbwfmgr`.

e.g.

`"C:\Users\JOHNDOE\SomeDir\fbwfmgr“`

**Note**

You will almost certainly need to run the batch script with administrative privileges too! I know you said you are logged in as the administrator, but you need to be certain that you have the permission for the script to be running especially as you are running it from another application, *(inno)*.

Comment: This did not help, I've edited the post to reflect this.On a side note, why did someone upvote your answer without testing that it actually worked?

Comment: Can you update your code to reflect it then please so that we can see exactly what you have tried now!