# PowerShell script executed from Inno Setup is failing with "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed - error 80040154"

Tags: powershell, iis, com, inno-setup

I want to convert a folder to an application with IIS using Inno Setup.

I found that I can do it with PowerShell, using

```
ConvertTo-WebApplication 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\MY_APP'
```

I have added this to my Inno Setup script:

```
[Run]
Filename: "powershell.exe"; \
  Parameters: "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ConvertTo-WebApplication 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\MY_APP'" \
  WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: runhidden
```

But PowerShell is failing with:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {XXXX} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Inno Setup in a 32-bit application, it will by default run 32-bit version of PowerShell, which in turn will use 32-bit COM classes.

The COM class needed for `ConvertTo-WebApplication` seems to be available (or registered) for 64-bit only.

Add the [`Flags: 64bit`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=64bit) to make Inno Setup use 64-bit version of PowerShell.

```
[Run]
Filename: "powershell.exe"; \
  Parameters: "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ConvertTo-WebApplication 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\MY_APP'" \
  WorkingDir: {app}; Flags: runhidden 64bit
```

---

Or use the [64-bit install mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls).

---

*For a similar question, see [A command in a .bat file is unrecognized when the .bat file is called from an Inno Setup but works fine when I run the bat file manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41397013/850848)*.